# how to sort sql data for given table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
+---------+----------------+--------+
|   aid   |       fn       | col_no |
+---------+----------------+--------+
| 2011768 | ABDUL          |      5 |
| 2011499 | ABDULLA        |      4 |
| 2011198 | ADNAN          |      3 |
| 2011590 | AKSHAYA PRAISY |      2 |
| 2011749 | AMIR           |      1 |
| 2011213 | AMOGHA         |      5 |
| 2011027 | ANU            |      4 |
| 2011046 | ANUDEV D       |      3 |
| 2011435 | B S SAHANA     |      2 |
| 2011112 | BENAKA         |      1 |
+---------+----------------+--------+
```

How to sort the number like col_no as 1 2 3 4 5 and again repeat as 1 2 3 4 5?

i need output like this

```
+---------+----------------+--------+
|   aid   |       fn       | col_no |
+---------+----------------+--------+
| 2011749 | AMIR           |      1 |
| 2011590 | AKSHAYA PRAISY |      2 |
| 2011198 | ADNAN          |      3 |
| 2011499 | ABDULLA        |      4 |
| 2011768 | ABDUL          |      5 |
| 2011112 | BENAKA         |      1 |
| 2011435 | B S SAHANA     |      2 |
| 2011046 | ANUDEV D       |      3 |
| 2011027 | ANU            |      4 |
| 2011213 | AMOGHA         |      5 |
+---------+----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` partition by `col_no`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by col_no order by fn),
         col_no;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3780d768347ec2aad5eb56a4b682292f) is a db<>fiddle.